# Issue with GetOpenFileName while debugging

Tags: c++, winapi

I have this simple program:

```cpp
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>

int main() {
    WCHAR Filestring[MAX_PATH] = L"\0";
    OPENFILENAMEW ofn = { 0 };
    ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(ofn);
    ofn.lpstrFile = Filestring;
    ofn.nMaxFile = MAX_PATH;
    if (GetOpenFileNameW(&ofn))
    {
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is my "simple reproducible example".

When I run this in my Visual Studio, it crashes at `GetOpenFileNameW`.

Why? I don't know. But when I run the application from the file path instead of debugging, it's fine and it opens the dialog like's it's supposed to.

I realized it's an issue with my situation rather than the code, so I completely reinstalled windows!

After, it worked fine when I tested it. But 5 hours later, I'm getting the same error.

Here is my error:

[image]

Anyone know what to do?

This code used to work, because I just grabbed it from an earlier project that just worked, until very recently for no reason.

Comment: What happens if you tell the debugger to continue? Do you perhaps have the debugger breaking on first chance exceptions? https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/understanding-exceptions-while-debugging-with-visual-studio/

Comment: This is not a crash. [DebugBreak and __debugbreak](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugbreak-and-debugbreak) explains what the message is trying to tell you: You've hit a breakpoint.

Comment: Some APIs do have internal breakpoints (whether intentional or not). If a debugger hits them and you don't want to break on them, just tell the debugger to continue.

Answer (score -5):

**I fixed it**

I realized CMake was breaking it. I uninstalled it and it fixed it. WEIRD?

Comment: How did you come to this realization? It is very unlikely that CMake actually broke anything. And it doesn't explain why uninstalling CMake would fix your project. This (lack of) information is not likely to help future readers.

Comment: I don't really know why. I just uninstalled it and it fixed it. I think there might have been files conflicting with the visual studio debugger. not sure. Since I reinstalled windows, this is pretty reproducible. Just install cmake and visual studio on a clean windows installation and try running the code above.

Comment: Thousands of people install CMake and VS and Windows and don't run into this problem. This sounds like something particular to your particular system/environment.